# powermock running with MockitToRunner - getting matchers error

Tags: powermockito

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MessageDataTest {
@InjectMocks
MessageData messageData;

@Test
  public void testingMethod() throws Exception {

        MessageData data = PowerMockito.spy(messageData);  //passing the mocked object for spy
        PowerMockito.when(data,"isMessageContains",anyString(),any()).thenReturn(true);  // throwing exception here
        MessageDataResponse response = messageFormatterData.constructData(messageItems);  
        assertNotNull(response);
    }
    }
```

MessageData.java

```
    private boolean isMessageContains(String name, MessageResponse messageResponse) {

        for (::) {
            some logic
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

when I run the test case, I'm getting the below error,

org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: Misplaced argument matcher detected here
You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing. Examples of correct usage of argument matchers: when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null); doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject()); verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))
Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with methods that cannot be mocked. Following methods cannot be stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode(). Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported

I want to mock this private "isMessageContains" to return always true.

Comment: org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Misplaced argument matcher detected here:

Comment: You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))

Comment: Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with methods that cannot be mocked.
Following methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode().
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.

Comment: Add all These comments to your question using the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52151773/edit) link